# Where to find documentation on jain-sip

Tags: java, documentation, sip, jain-sip

The title is as clear as it gets. I'm searching for the jain-sip documentation but I'm unable to find it. There is a a link to [documentation](http://jsip.java.net/) at the [jsip.java.net](http://jsip.java.net/) website but I get send to the hudson builder.

Answer (score 2):

The latest JAIN-SIP javadoc is no longer hosted nor built by Jboss. To locate the latest stuff try the official project site first: https://java.net/projects/jsip

To save some time, here is the latest build spot as of 5/28/14:
https://mobicents.ci.cloudbees.com/job/JAIN-SIP/

Comment: This answers the question just fine. He could copy/paste then entire jain-sip documentation here, but this wasn't what was asked for, and it very possibly clutters up the site unnecessarily. The point about the posting of only links is valid (that they might become broken at some point), but the documentation itself might also become obsolete. Posting a snapshot of it here won't be of any more use, and might even detract if it is not obvious that the documentation is out-of-date or in flux. The best we can do is hope the link stays appropriate, and that it is properly updated.

Comment: As a matter of fact those links are now dead; I had to go looking for new ones. This really sucks when its supposed to be a "top-level" java project.

Comment: I was able to follow the links in the answer to: https://jsip.ci.cloudbees.com/job/jsip/javadoc/. Just a few clicks and I was there. I think that counts as still valid.

Comment: I edited the links after i made that comment.. they're good as of that day

Comment: So you're now the custodian of this link? :)

Comment: I guess its fitting since I can't seem to keep away from SIP in one way or another..

Answer (score 0):

You can also find a proper javadoc on the following link [JAIN-SIP javadoc](https://developer.opencloud.com/devportal/devportal/apis/jainsip/1.1/docs/index.html). It has the API's in the typical javadocs style.